# How to map a function with several arguments

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a function definition like this:

```
f x y z = ...
```

Now I have a list of each of the argument: [x],[y],[z]

How do I somehow map f over all the corresponding element in each list? That is, i want only the first element(or the second, third, but not with different positions) from all the lists to be applied to the function.
For example:

```
f x1 y1 z1
f x2 y2 z2
```

but not

```
f x1 y2 z3 etc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want the Prelude function [zipWith3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith3)

Comment: … and Hoogle can [help you (osager) find it](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c%20-%3E%20d%29%20-%3E%20[a]%20-%3E%20[b]%20-%3E%20[c]%20-%3E%20[d]).